# How to Automatically Turn on a Computer at a Specified Time

Tags: c++, windows, boot

I am writing a C++ program.
this program when running should get a time and after shut down system , automatically turn on at specified time.
I searched but could not find my questions answer.
My OS is windows 7 and 8.
my hardware is 1- motherboard : Asus , CPU : AMD   or   2- motherboard : Gigabyte , CPU : Intel
Thanks.

Comment: have a look at the second answer to this post. I think you need to play with bios settings but I never tried it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774851/change-bios-settings-using-the-c-language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As some people have said, and as far as I can find it is not possible to schedule a normal PC turn on for a considerable range of PCs unless you use another machine and the [wake on LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) capability.
However you could use [waitable timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to wake from hibernation or suspension. Two sates that can be reached programmatically via the [SetSuspendState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373201%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function. Other
three Windows API functions will help you with the second approach:

1. [CreateWaitableTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. [SetWaitableTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686289%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
3. [CancelWaitableTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I do not recommend to hack any BIOS configuration at all. For safety just use what your system provides in the form of a well documented API. Those hacks sometimes lead to undesired or unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I've redone this answer in response to the comment left...

Firstly for the shutdown command try the following:

```
main()
{
          system("c:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\shutdown /s /t 0");
          return 0; 
}
```

[Further information at this tutorial](http://teckguide.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/c-code-to-shut-down-computer-want-to-do.html)

Now for waking up...
I don't think it's possible to start on a desktop without Wake-On-Lan in the BIOS, and setting up a client to send it the magic packet.

So the best way I reckon is to have a device sitting on the same subnet to handle the sending of the start up magic packet... not an awesome option but if definite shutdown is what you are looking for then there are limited ways of getting it back on without manually doing so.

Just as background the magic packet address frame is done in the following format - 6*255 aka 0xFF, destination MAC address repeated 16 times. So if your MAC address is 01:02:03:04:05:06 the frame would look like like so:

FFFFFFFFFFFF010203040506010203040506010203040506010203040506
010203040506010203040506010203040506010203040506010203040506
010203040506010203040506010203040506010203040506010203040506
010203040506010203040506

[See WOL Mini HOWTO - Chapter 2](http://gsd.di.uminho.pt/jpo/software/wakeonlan/mini-howto/wol-mini-howto-2.html)

In c++ the packet itself can be constructed like so, entering in each section of your destination address converted.

```
unsigned char tosend[102];
unsigned char mac[6];

/** first 6 bytes of 255 **/
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
tosend[i] = 0xFF;
}
/** store mac address **/
mac[0] = 0x01;
mac[1] = 0x02;
mac[2] = 0x03;
mac[3] = 0x04;
mac[4] = 0x05;
mac[5] = 0x06;
/** append it 16 times to packet **/
for(int i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
memcpy(&tosend[i * 6], &mac, 6 * sizeof(unsigned char));
}
```

Then create a sender as like so, which will broadcast the packet to all devices on the subnet but the frame just constructed communicates the MAC address:

```
int udpSocket;
struct sockaddr_in udpClient, udpServer;
int broadcast = 1;

udpSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

/** you need to set this so you can broadcast **/
if (setsockopt(udpSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcast, sizeof broadcast) == -1)     {
perror(“setsockopt (SO_BROADCAST)”);
exit(1);
}

udpClient.sin_family = AF_INET;
udpClient.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
udpClient.sin_port = 0;

bind(udpSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&udpClient, sizeof(udpClient));

/**make packet as shown above**/

**/** set server end point (the broadcast address)**/
udpServer.sin_family = AF_INET;
udpServer.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(“192.168.1.255″);
udpServer.sin_port = htons(9);

/** send the packet **/
sendto(udpSocket, &tosend, sizeof(unsigned char) * 102, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&udpServer,     sizeof(udpServer));**
```

[Wake on LAN tutorial - reference for C++ example](http://shadesfgray.wordpress.com/2010/12/17/wake-on-lan-how-to-tutorial/)

Comment: since you did make this an answer, go all the way. External links without any material here are considered bad because they can become invalidated so future readers won’t gain anything from your answer. Put the essential points from that tutorial here (adapt them for the OP needs if necessary) and I'll upvote your answer.

Comment: Thanks bolov - I have redone my answer as directed. Thank you for providing feedback instead of the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can shutdown using a batch file and coding in that. 
It is not possible to switch on the computer once it is shutdown in any language as this is a hardware requirement.

Comment: but some program ( for example "Auto PowerOn & ShutDown" ) automatically turn on at specified time

Comment: @negarsalehi, that program looks like it only wakes the computer up rather than actually turning it on.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically turn on a computer from sleep mode (not power off state).

As a second option, you could add some custom external hardware to trigger a turn on event (power switch pressed, Wake on LAN, Wake on Ring, keyboard spacebar press, direct green-black wires contact on the power supply cabling and many others)

An example of a DIY programmable WOL magic packet sender: 
http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,15330.0.html

Obviously such hardware should be programmable when the computer is on

Comment: but some program ( for example "Auto PowerOn & ShutDown" ) automatically turn on at specified time

Comment: @negarsalehi they can wake up only from sleep or hibernation (by their claim). Not from a full shut-down.

Answer (score 0):

You can shut down your PC invoking the shutdown command using the shell.

for starting up ,most BIOS supports wake on LAN.

You will have to run your program on a second PC, and send some packets usually called magic packets addressed using MAC the LAN of your PC to be turned on.

You can read about it more here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN